# Whie training I am getting the following error. " ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I calculated gradients but still I am getting no gradient error.I am not able to figure out where I am missing even after looking at answers to similar type of errors.
I am using tensorflow 2.
The link to my code is https://github.com/Gadamsetty/ML_practise/blob/master/translatron_test.py

the error is as follows

```
ValueError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-15-031ef53603dd>:92 train_step  *
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients,variables))
    /tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:427 apply_gradients
        grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
    /tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:1025 _filter_grads
        ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['encoder_rnn_3/layer0/forward_gru_12/kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer0/forward_gru_12/recurrent_kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer0/forward_gru_12/bias:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer0/backward_gru_12/kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer0/backward_gru_12/recurrent_kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer0/backward_gru_12/bias:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer1/forward_gru_13/kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer1/forward_gru_13/recurrent_kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer1/forward_gru_13/bias:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer1/backward_gru_13/kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer1/backward_gru_13/recurrent_kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer1/backward_gru_13/bias:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer2/forward_gru_14/kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer2/forward_gru_14/recurrent_kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer2/forward_gru_14/bias:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer2/backward_gru_14/kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer2/backward_gru_14/recurrent_kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer2/backward_gru_14/bias:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer3/forward_gru_15/kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer3/forward_gru_15/recurrent_kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer3/forward_gru_15/bias:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer3/backward_gru_15/kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer3/backward_gru_15/recurrent_kernel:0', 'encoder_rnn_3/layer3/backward_gru_15/bias:0', 'decoder_rnn_3/bidirectional_6/forward_decoder_layer1/kernel:0', 'decoder_rnn_3/bidirectional_6/forward_decoder_layer1/recurrent_kernel:0', 'decoder_rnn_3/bidirectional_6/forward_decoder_layer1/bias:0', 'decoder_...
```

Comment: Could you give some extra information about the code? The first thing that comes to my mind is that maybe you are computing the loss in an undifferentiable way. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to implement speech translation that takes spectrogram of source speech and predict the spectrogram of the target speech. I am very glad that you gave a comment.Can you please review my code in the link and suggest possible correction?

Comment: I have calculated two types of losses , mean squared loss for spectrogram prediction and cross entropy loss for stop token prediction. I added two losses and tried to minimize them by optimization but when i printed the calculated gradients I got a list like [None ,,,,, None]

Comment: Since you are not doing any operation on the gradients, can you try to use directly ‘optimizer.minimize(loss)‘ rather than first computing gradients and then applying them separately? (lines 159-161)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggetion.I have corrected the mistake

Comment: Great! I will add this in the comments below so that you can accept it as a solution :)  happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not doing any operation on the gradients, you can try to use directly `optimizer.minimize(loss)` rather than first computing gradients and then applying them separately. (lines 159-161)